# Some RxJs questions

Tags: rxjs

I'm learning RxJs and have several questions

1. Is it necessary to unsubscribe from the create-operations like from, of?

```
of([1, 2, 3]).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

2. Whats the difference between the following three versions:

```
 this.free$.next(true);
```

version 1:

```
    this.free$.subscribe(value => {
      if (value) {
        // do something
      }
    });
```

version 2

```
    this.free$.pipe(
        tap(value => {
            if (value)  {
                // do something
            }
        } )
    ).subscribe();
```

and version 3:

```
    this.free$.subscribe({
        next: value => {
            if (value) {
              // do something;
            }
          }
    });
```

Which version better and why? Whats the difference between version 1 and version 2? The result seems to be the same for every version.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to unsubscribe

Depends. If an observable may not emit an `error` or `complete`, then you'll want to be sure to unsubscribe somehow (There are other operators like `take`, `takeWhile`, and `takeUntil` that can do this for you declaratively).

The example you gave does not need to be unsubscribed as it'll always complete.

---

> Whats the difference between the following three versions:

1) & 3) are similar. The first subscribes with a lambda and the second subscribes with an object. I prefer the object as it allows you to define behaviour for the other events of an Observable as well:

```js
this.free$.subscribe({
  next: val => ...,
  error: err => ...,
  complete: () => ...
});
```

This object can define any of these 3 and in any order.

```js
this.free$.subscribe({
  complete: () => console.log("Complete"),
  error: console.log
});
```

2) has similar behaviour to 1) & 3) if you only subscribe once. If you subscribe multiple times, two's `// do something` will be "duplicated"

```ts
const freeTap$ = this.free$.pipe(
  tap(value => {
    if (value)  {
      // do something
    }
  } )
);

freeTap$.subscribe(_ => console.log("First Subscription"));
freeTap$.subscribe(_ => console.log("Second Subscription"));
```

That is to say, `tap` created a side-effect for subscribing to and receiving emissions for this stream. This side effect is built into the stream itself.

I avoid side effects where possible as they're an easy cause of bugs and spaghetti-code.

Answer (score 1):

1. As per the documentation of `of`:

> An Observable that emits the arguments described above and then completes.

Since the Observable completes, you don't need to unsubscribe. However, some teams define a general coding guideline of "if you subscribe you should always unsubscribe" for safety.

2. Here is the difference:

**version 1**: This is passing the `next` function implementation. This requires that the code specifically subscribe because that is how the emitted value is handled. And the code should then manage the subscription and unsubscribe.

**version 2**: This is using the pipeable operators to perform the operation. Since it's using `tap`, it doesn't modify the incoming emitted value. Using the `pipe` allows you to perform numerous operations (filter, combine, reformat, get related data, etc) against the emitted item.

This does *not* require the subscribe since the emitted value is handled in through the pipeline. This means that you can instead use the `async` pipe. The `async` pipe automatically handles the subscribe and unsubscribe for you and allows for OnPush change detection.

This is the option that is often recommended as it provides the most flexibility in working with the emitted items and improved UI performance.

**version 3**: This is passing an `Observer` object to the subscribe method. Use this technique if you want to also define an `error` or `complete` function as part of the `Observer`.

[image]

[image]

If you are interested in more information, the first talk at this user group covers "RxJS Terms, Tips, and Techniques": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSsch65n8Yw

NOTE: I was already mostly through my draft when the answer appeared and decided to post mine as well since it was a bit different.